# how to get result of query linq in view razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have below join query but I dont know access to like in view

```
var SearchPost = (from p in db.Posters 
                             where p.CityID == CityID
                             join a in db.Assessments
                             on p.PosterID equals a.PosterID into search
                             select new { p, like = search.Where((a => a.PosterID == p.PosterID)).Count() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SearchPost` is anonymous object, so you have to map `SearchPost` object to another model. create new Model:

```
public class PostSearchResult
{
    public Poster Poster { get; set; }
    public int LikeCount { get; set;}
}
```

and then:

```
var searchPost = (from p in db.Posters 
                  where p.CityID == CityID
                  join a in db.Assessments
                  on p.PosterID equals a.PosterID into search
                  select new { p, like = search.Where((a => a.PosterID == p.PosterID)).Count() }
                 )
                .ToList();

var searchResult = searchPost
    .Select(s => new PostSearchResult { Poster = s.p, LikeCount = s.like})
    .ToList();
```

then return `searchResult` to `View`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `SearchPost` result in your Action method (i.e., `return View(SearchPost);`). Then in your .cshtml file, you would declare `@model MyNameSpace.Models.Poster` where `MyNameSpace` is the name of your namespace and Poster is your model class in your `Models` folder. (You obviously need to change `@model MyNameSpace.Models.Poster`).

Then, you can access your `Poster` model in your razor view page using `@Model` (i.e., `@Model.PosterID` or `@Model.Assessment.PosterID` or whatever).

Comment: SearchPost no model class. I have table Poster and table Assessment and I want get data in table poster and count like of each post.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said Poster model class instead of SearchPost model class. I've updated my answer. The idea is the same, but changed `SearchPost` to `Poster`.